# How to assign specific CSV headers to a specific data in Rails CSV generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to implement CSV file generator for admin logs. The thing is I want to have table with data like below:

```
Date & time | Action     | Acting User | Old Data | New Data
------------|------------|-------------|----------|----------
created_at  | action_type| admin_email | old_data | new_data
```

I don't know how to assign those headers (data&time, action, etc.) to a specific row (created_at, action_type, etc.)

This is what I have right now

```
class CsvAdminLogGenerator
  LOG_HEADERS = ['Date&Time', 'Action', 'Acting User', 'Old Data', 'New Data'].freeze

  def initialize(start_date:, end_date:)
    @start_date = start_date
    @end_date = end_date
  end

  def build_csv_file
    AdminPanelLog.dates_between(start_date, end_date).each do |admin_log|
      CSV.generate(headers: LOG_HEADERS, col_sep: ';', encoding: 'UTF-8') do |csv|
        csv << admin_log.created_at
        csv << admin_log.action_type
        csv << admin_log.admin_email
        csv << admin_log.old_data
        csv << admin_log.new_data
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: you're generating a CSV file per each AdminPanelLog record. Is this intended?

Comment: @JoshBrody I want to have a solution that will reflect this scenario - user want to have all admin logs form 01.2019 till 07.2019 and those data should be in one CSV file. AdminPanelLog is a model which store specific data like `action_type`, `admin_email` etc.

Comment: You're iterating over each AdminPanelLog and generating a new CSV file. You need to reverse that order.

Comment: I don't understand, how to do so? I thought it was enough to create csv file in case like I wrote before.